# <li> List tag wrapped content doesn’t start from the same position when multiple lines

Tags: html, css

1. I have created an unordered list and used `list-style-type:none` and `list-style-position: outside`.
2. I am also using the `li::before` css psuedo-element to remove default bullet points and add a custom color and fonts for bullets.
3. In the above scenario, when we have multiple lines of text for the bullet points the text on the second line is not aligned with the first line.

How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
  .test-feature ul {
      list-style: disc outside none;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 1em;
      text-indent: -1.75em;
    }

.test-feature ul li::before {
      content: "\2022";
      color: yellow;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1em;
      font-size: 2.2em;
      line-height: 0px;
      padding-left: 1em;
      position: relative;
      top: 0.2em;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me your html and css? That would be a big help.

Comment: Please review [ask], and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55166876/edit) your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Ibra my apology for not posting the code. i have edited the question with the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to accomplish this

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: -1.3em;
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  line-height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.3em;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    line1<br />
    line2<br />
    line3<br />
    line4
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sweet. Would you like to accept this as the answer then? ^-^